# Graphics with higher resolution in Desktop version become pixelated when deployed to Wolfram Cloud

Tags: graphics, wolfram-cloud

My project is to process images in Mathematica, such that given a list of checkboxes, the function will take specific coordinates from these processed images (imageValuePositions[]), and mark a background image at these coordinates. This works perfectly in the desktop version of Mathematica, however, when the output graphic is deployed to Wolfram Cloud the graphic loses resolution and gets pixelated (circle dots from the original graphic become squares in the cloud). The marks made on this background graphic retain the resolution, and it is just the graphic itself that suffers this problem. I have seen multiple threads about this error but no resolution so far. On the left is the original graphic in Mathematica desktop, and to the right is the pixelated graphic deployed to the cloud. [image: desktop image (left), Cloud image (right)]

```
CloudDeploy[
Dynamic[Legended[
   Dynamic[HighlightImage[croppedBlanktSNEMass, 
     Table[ImageMarker[
      markingMergeMass[[
         Sort[Flatten[
            Table[Position[gateNameMass, 
              showOrHideMass[[x]][[1]]], {x, 
              Length[showOrHideMass]}]]][[x]]]][[1]], 
       Graphics[{markingMergeMass[[
           Sort[Flatten[
              Table[Position[gateNameMass, 
                showOrHideMass[[x]][[1]]], {x, 
                Length[showOrHideMass]}]]][[x]]]][[2]], 
         Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.009]]}]], {x, 
       Length[Sort[
         Flatten[Table[
           Position[gateNameMass, showOrHideMass[[x]][[1]]], {x, 
            Length[showOrHideMass]}]]]]}], "Darken", 
     ImageSize -> Large]], 
   Table[CheckboxBar[
     Dynamic[showOrHideMass], {{gateNameMass[[x]], 
       Flatten[Prepend[colorMarkMass, 
          Table[colorMarkIndependentMass[[x]], {x, 
            Length[colorMarkIndependentMass]}]]][[x]], 
       markerCombosCheckOriginMass[[x]]}}], {x, 
     Length[gateNameMass]}]]]
```

1. croppedBlanktSNEMass = background image you see in output, Head[] = Image, after running code the output Head[] = Graphics.
2. markingMergeMass = list of coordinates from ImageValuePositions[], length depends on how many markers I started with. If started with 2 markers, Length[] = 2. list made of nested lists each with 2 indices. index 1 is list of all coordinates, index 2 is an RGB color for visualization.
3. gateNameMass is list of user-friendly strings corresponding to number of populations selected. in this example I chose 3 populations, each of which have gateNameMass prepended in legend. example {hello,tree,bye}.
4. showOrHideMass corresponds to checkpoints checked in legend. if nothing is checked then showOrHideMass = {}. if middle is checked then showOrHideMass = {{{CD1},{Bright}}, RGB green}.
5. colorMarkMass and colorMarkIndependentMass are the RGB colors corresponding to populations chosen at begining. Notice the first checkbox in legend has different population format compared to the other 2, there is no nested list at 3rd index, this is colorMarkIndependentMass. in this case {light yello/green}. colorMarkMass is {green,blue}.
6. markerCombosCheckOriginMass = list of all populations (3rd index in legend) from top to bottom. Example, {{CD1,All Stains},{{CD1},{Bright}},{{CD1,CD2},{All,ALL}}}.

Problem is that even if I do not input all the code in CloudDeploy[] and simply copy paste the output graphic in cloudDeploy[], I get same pixelation problem in cloud.

I would appreciate all help. If additional information is needed please ask.

Additional Information:

Mathematica Desktop version: 12.3.1.

Running this code in version 13.1.0 produced pixelated output like the one in Wolfram Cloud.
When I download the pixelated file from wolfram cloud (13.1.0) to wolfram player (12.3.1) I get the original (higher resolution) output.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Code is added with variable information.